# Mongoose is only returning ID from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datatables

I am currently trying to incorporate datatables with my MongoDB database. I am having some trouble accessing the returned object though. The main problem I am seeing is that I am only getting the _id returned from MongoDB, and no values of the object.

Heres the code I am using to pass the information to the datatables.

```
var itemsModel = require('./models/itemReturn');

exports.getItemList = function(req, res) {

  var searchStr = req.body.search.value;
  if (req.body.search.value) {
    var regex = new RegExp(req.body.search.value, "i")
    searchStr = { $or: [{ 'productName': regex }, { 'itemPrice': regex }, { 'Quantity': regex }, { 'Description': regex }, { 'seller': regex }] };
  } else {
    searchStr = {};
  }

  var recordsTotal = 0;
  var recordsFiltered = 0;

  itemsModel.count({}, function(err, c) {
    recordsTotal = c;
    console.log(c);
    itemsModel.count(searchStr, function(err, c) {
      recordsFiltered = c;
      itemsModel.find(searchStr, 'productName itemPrice Quantity Description seller', { 'skip': Number(req.body.start), 'limit': Number(req.body.length) }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('error while getting results' + err);
          return;
        }
        var data = JSON.stringify({
          "draw": req.body.draw,
          "recordsFiltered": recordsFiltered,
          "recordsTotal": recordsTotal,
          "data": results
        });
        console.log(data);
        res.send(data);
      });

    });
  });
};
```

This is the model

```
// app/models/itemsReturn.js
// load the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var schemaOptions = {
  timestamps: true,
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true
  },
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true
  }
};


// define the schema for our item model
var itemsReturned = mongoose.Schema({
  productName: String,
  itemPrice: String,
  Quantity: String,
  Description: String,
  seller: String
}, schemaOptions);


// create the model for users and expose it to our app
var items = mongoose.model('items', itemsReturned);
module.exports = items;
```

The thing is that I know its not a data table issue as I can make the _id appear in the tables. I just need to know how to return the entire object instead of just the _ID so that I can access the values of the object.

[If it helps this is the tutorial I am following.](https://medium.com/@deepika.gunda/series-datatables-with-nodejs-express-and-mongodb-part1-get-a-database-to-work-with-7ce78848023e)

UPDATE: Okay so I figured out why my MongoDB collections were only returning the item ID. The issue was that I had stored everything in the local database (oops).

Comment: You are getting only `_ids` in `result` ? if so please try with removing fields from query and check what you get and also you can print the query, get better idea what is the problem

Comment: Yeah, so the only thing that result is returning are the _ids of the objects within MongoDB.

Comment: have you print the queries with `mongoose.set('debug',true)` ?

Comment: I have not I can try that tomorrow and get back to you with the results